# Error on VS Code but not on Dartpad. - Field 'percent' should be initialized because its type 'double' doesn't allow null

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run this code:

```
void main() {
  var studentSample = Student();
  studentSample.name = "Peter";
  print(studentSample.name);

  studentSample.percentage = 438;
  print(studentSample.percentage);
}

class Student {
  String name;

  double percent;

  set percentage(double marksSecured) {
    percent = (marksSecured / 500) * 100;
  }

  double get percentage {
    return percent;
  }
}
```

When run on Visual Studio Code, an error occurs saying

```
main.dart:13:10: Error: Field 'percent' should be initialized because its type 'double' doesn't allow null.
  double percent;
```

However, it works on DartPad with this result:

```
Peter
87.6
```

How do I make VS Code run this code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new standard would be to use [Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

```
double? percent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize `percent`.

`double percent = 0.0;`

Answer (score 0):

-> References to understand the null saftey
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety
https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/

double percent = 0.0;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).